# What does "two-, three-and four-doughnut days" mean?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie *Bombshell* (2019), Kayla follows Faye to the elevator:

> Faye: Well, I work for Roger. We have **two-, three-and four-doughnut
> days**.
>
> Kayla: Sugar does make everybody crazy.
>
> Faye: No, these aren't doughnuts he eats. They're doughnuts he throws.
> At somebody.

What does "two-, three-and four-doughnut days" mean?

Comment: It's about the *kind* of day they are having. Similarly, a job of work might be a one-cigarette job, a two- or a three-cigarette job (I am not advocating smoking).

Comment: The fictional detective Sherlock Holmes measured the difficulty of problems by the number of pipes of tobacco he needed to smoke while solving them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is “days” rather than “day.”

Second, the normal meaning of the phrase would be “Some days, he eats two doughnuts; some days he eats three doughnuts, and some days he eats four doughnuts.”

Why can we assume that it is telling about how many doughnuts he eats? Because that is what 99.999999% of the population does with doughnuts.

It is highly condensed, informal speech.

Third, this is a joke because in this case it means “Some days he throws two doughnuts at people; other days he throws three”....